# Why do second-level properties not show up in BindingManagerBase?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have a class with second-level properties that is bound to controls on my form using a BindingSource. That part works fine: the data is displayed and changes are propagated to the bound object.

Now I need to enumerate all databindings. My approach is to loop over the Bindings property of the BindingManagerBase. Unfortunatly, the collection does not contain the second-level properties.

Could somebody kindly explain why I don't see the second-level properties? Alternatively, if there is a different approach to iterate over alle bindings including the second-level properties I would be happy, too.

To illustrate my problem I created a minimal example. To use the following code add two textboxes to an empty form and add the code to the form's Load-event:

```
Dim bs = New BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = GetType(OuterClass)

TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "OuterValue")
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Inner.InnerValue")

Dim mgr As BindingManagerBase = BindingContext(bs)
For Each b As Binding In mgr.Bindings
     Debug.Print(b.BindingMemberInfo.BindingField)
Next
```

The Debug.Print will only print "OuterValue" because that is the only binding in mgr.Bindings which is the problem I have.

The used classes in the above code are defined as follows:

```
Public Class OuterClass
    Property OuterValue As String
    Property Inner As InnterClass
End Class

Public Class InnterClass
    Property InnerValue As String
End Class
```

Sascha

Comment: 1) _nested class_ -- a class defined within another class -- is probably not what you mean here. Consider using _second-level properties_. 2) Just to confirm, changes to second-level properties are also propagated?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thanks for pointing out that "nested" is not the correct adjectiv. I changed my post accordingly.

Yes, I just confirmed that changes are propagated even to the second-level properties. That works fine which I find even more confusing. If the binding works, why are second-level properties not in the Bindings-List...